# how to find all files containing many different strings and document it(windows)

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to find all references to SQL tables in c# code.  there are 500 tables and several hundred files in the solution.  What i would like to end up with as a file containing a delimited list like this

Table1,  codefile.cs
Table1,  codefile2.cs
Table2,  codefile.cs
Table3,  codefile4.cs

the best answer I can come up with is create a batch file that runs findstr and then massage the data into a table.  I am just wondering if there is a tool that will do something like this for me.
thank you 
KevCri

Comment: Are all the tables in all files named adhering to the same format `Table{digit}`?

Comment: no the tables are named based on what is in them, not actually named table1,table2 etc

Comment: Then how would you know it's a table, looking at your code files from a purely text file perspective?

Comment: I have a list of all the table names

Comment: My guess would be, if you have a list of all the table names, but them in a list, load , open the directory with your project in it from code, a Iterate recursively through all the files, load each one by one using a filestream, then read all lines, check each line against the List of tables,( keep a count variable), and whne you find the table name, update a file with the count of where the table is. and so on

Comment: Please share your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- You have your file names in tables.txt, one table per line
- All your .cs files are in your current directory

Then the following batch script should give you what you want

```
@echo off
>tableReferences.txt (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%T in ("tables.txt") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%F iin ('findstr /mirc:"\<%%T\>" *.cs') do (
      echo %%T, %%F
    )
  )
)
```

If you need to search a file hierarchy, then add /S to the FINDSTR options.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a C# program like this.

**NOTE:**

Make sure to pass the project/solution directory in place of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> TableNames = new List<string>() { "Table1", "Table3", "Table5", "Table7" };
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                var contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var result = TableNames.FindAll(contents.Contains);
                if (result.Count > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    foreach (var table in result)
                    {
                        results.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", table, fileName));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And write the `results` to a file if you would like:

```
File.WriteAllLines("Output.txt", results.ToArray());
```